# current_user in Phoenix controller passed by Plug

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Takes this code example as a Plug to handle authentication:

```
defmodule Financeweb.APIAuth do
...

  def call(conn, _opts) do
  ...

    if authenticated_user do
      conn
      |> assign(:current_user, user)
    else
      conn
      |> send_resp(401, "{\"error\":\"unauthorized\"}")
      |> halt
    end
  end
end
```

So, I'm passing the variable `current_user` downstream via `Plug.Conn.assign/3`. What's the best way to get this variable in a Phoenix controller? I'm doing this way (code below), but i'm sure that there's a better way to do that.

```
def index(conn, _) do
  user_id = conn.assigns.current_user.id 
end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

override `action/2` and inject it:

```
def action(conn, _) do
  apply(__MODULE__, action_name(conn),
    [conn, conn.params, conn.assigns.current_user])
end

def index(conn, _params, current_user) do
  ...
end

def show(conn, _params, current_user) do
  ...
end
```